# Autocomplete JSON response not working

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, response

im getting response in json (can check in firebug), but this wont parse the json response and no results displayed. what m i doing wrong? i could'nt find anything on doc http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Here is my JSON response

```
({"Contacts":[{"Phone":"","Email":"","Labels":"","Mobile":"12345678","Firstname":"john"}]});
```

And This is my jQuery:

```
$("#destinations").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/contactApi.do?callback=?", 
          { 'contactMobile': request.term, maxRows: 12, style: "full" }, 
          function(data) {
              if(data.Contacts){
                  var x = $.map(data.Contacts, function(v, i){
                      console.log(v)
                      return {
                          label: v.Mobile + ' - ' + v.Firstname, 
                          v: v.Firstname
                      }
                  });
                  response(x);
              }
          }
        );        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once that the problem was on the server side. I was sending the response as a raw string instead of JSON. Take a look in firebug if you are able to see the proper headers (content-type:application/json) being sent back from the server. Also you should be able to see a tab named JSON using firebug. After I added the proper headers I was able to deserialize the values using jQuery.